# Error when trying to load google play stats to google bigquery

Tags: google-play, google-bigquery

I am trying to run a load job that populates a BQ table with data from the google play stats. the source file is a CSV that was created by Google on Google Play Developer Console.
Source file is hosted on Google Cloud in CSV format, Target is a BigQuery Table.
I keep getting this error: File: 0 / Line:1 / Field:1, Bad character (ASCII 0) encountered: field starts with: <>
With no hint regarding what the problem is.
can anyone suggest what should i do differently?

Job ID: playscape-proj:job_4K-6mCl1tvzE_t-zCMELgPUgLnI

Comment: From the error message, it sounds like your CSV file has a null character at the very beginning. Maybe double-check it in a hex editor?

Comment: Usually this is because in CSV the double-quote must be encoded by putting another double quote in front of it

Comment: I don't see the null character there. regarding missing double-quote... I know it is a big expectation, but I expected a CSV generated by one Google service to comply with load process of another Google service... I'd love to have a solution that not involve cleansing the file.

Comment: @N.N while I do understand the sentiment it should work (and I agree with you there) that should be something brought up to Google Play Services so you can have a CSV of stats that can load (I don't know if Google Play has an issue tracker but I'd believe this would be the proper channel for that). Right now, to answer your question here, Pentium's solution seems to be the right one, even if it shouldn't have to be done :(

Comment: Apprently its an encoding issue... Source csv is utf16 while gbq supports utf8 csvs. I'd still like to see compatibility between different google services.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the load job configuration you are sending is specifying compression as `GZIP`, yet the uri you provide appears to point to a raw CSV file. Uncompressing a non-compressed file might generate unexpected null values.

Comment: Not compressed... Its an encoding issue.